Show that $e^{tA}e^{tB}=e^{t(A+B)}e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}[A,B]}$
I need to prove that if $\big[A,[A,B]\big]=\big[B,[A,B]\big]=0$, where $[A,B]=BA-AB$, then
$$e^{tB}e^{tA}=e^{t(A+B)}e^{\frac{t^2}{2}[A,B]}$$
Hint: Consider the matrix equation $X' = t[A, B]X$, and prove that $e^{−t(A+B)}e^{tB}e^{tA}$ is solution. On the other hand, given an $n \times n$ matrix, prove that $e^{t^2 C/2}$ is a solution of $X^{\prime} = tCX$. Take $C$ convenient and conclude.
I try differentiating the function they give me to prove that it is the solution.
\begin{align*}
X'(t) &= \left( \frac{d}{dt} e^{-t(A+B)} \right) e^{tB} e^{tA} + e^{-t(A+B)} \left( \frac{d}{dt} e^{tB} \right) e^{tA} + e^{-t(A+B)} e^{tB} \left( \frac{d}{dt} e^{tA} \right)\\
&= - (A + B) e^{-t(A+B)} e^{tB} e^{tA} + e^{-t(A+B)} B e^{tB} e^{tA} + e^{-t(A+B)} e^{tB} A e^{tA}
\end{align*}
Now factoring,
\begin{align*}
X'(t) &= e^{-t(A+B)} \left( - (A + B)e^{tB} e^{tA} + Be^{tB} e^{tA} + e^{tB} e^{tA}A \right) \\
&= e^{-t(A+B)} \left( e^{tB} e^{tA}A -Ae^{tB} e^{tA} + Be^{tB} e^{tA} - Be^{tB} e^{tA}  \right) \\
&= e^{-t(A+B)}[A,e^{tB} e^{tA}]
\end{align*}
but I cannot prove that it is indeed the  solution.

What have you tried? Have you attempted using the hint?

Yes, I tried it but when I differentiate the equation they give me I get that the derivative is zero

OK - add your attempts to the question with an edit and then we can see what's gone wrong.

ok now add the attempt

$A$ does not commute with $e^{tB}$ ... so your "factoring" step is wrong

Thanks, I already corrected that but now I don't know how to continue

Isn't Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula of some help ?

Yes, that formula helps and solves it easily, but I asked and I can't use it for this exercise so, I guess there must be another way.

Consider the map
$$g(t) = e^{tB}A e^{-tB}.$$
If $\left[B,[A,B]\right]=0$, you get $g^\prime(t) = -[A,B]$. Hence $$g(t) = g(0) - t[A,B]=A -t[A,B].\tag{1}$$
Now using the identities $[A, BC] =[A, B]C + B[A,C]$ and $[A, e^{tA}] = 0$ in the formula $X^\prime(t) = e^{-t(A+B)}[A,e^{tB} e^{tA}]$ that you wrote in the question, you obtain:
$$X^\prime(t) = e^{-t(A+B)} [A,e^{tB}]e^{tA}.$$
From $(1)$, you get $[A,e^{tB}] = t[A,B] e^{tB}$ and finally
$$X^\prime(t) = e^{-t(A+B)}t[A,B] e^{tB}e^{tA} = t[A,B]X(t)$$ as desired because $[A,[A,B]]=[B,[A,B]]=0$ implies that $e^{-t(A+B)}$ and $[A,B]$ commute.
Note: this is Glauber formula. I get inspired by this proof that I adapted in the context of your question. The main idea is the introduction of the map $g$.

When I differentiate g i obtain [A,B] in positive. I think it's because the definition of
[A,B]=BA-AB it's backwards

Indeed, I use $[A,B] =AB-BA$. Which is more common I think. No?

Yes, that form is more common, but in this exercise it is defined backwards. Your development is fine, and in this case deriving and getting it positive also works since I need it positive because it is used backwards everywhere. Thank you so much :)
